# Как установить PySide6?

Tags: python, pyside6

Может я тупой, или тут что-то не так, но я не могу установить PySide6

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pip написал что нет версии под 32 битную систему или версию python. Нужна 64 битная

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, у вас установлена устаревшая версия Пайтона (необходима версия 3.9 и выше). Проверить можете с помощью команды в консоли "pip --version" (в конце в скобках будет ваша версия Пайтона)

Если же все сходится, скопируйте данную команду:
**pip install PySide6**

Comment: У меня стоит python 3.10, и всё равно не работает

Comment: Покажите вывод этой команды python --version.

Comment: ```pip 22.3.1 from C:\Users\HOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)```